# Visual Studio C# Manifest not finding files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, manifest

I am trying to use a library in my program, which requires me to use manifest dependencies, but Visual Studio won't build the executable, it says:

```
Error 15: Could not find file '<filename>, Version=0.0.0.0, Type=win32'.
```

Here is how it's defined, in it's own manifest file, which I've included as part of the project:

```
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Namespace.sdk.core" version="0.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

If I separate it out into a dependency manifest file (namespace.sdk.manifest), it says it can't find that file: (I substituted the actual name for namespace.sdk for privacy):

```
 <dependency>
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Namespace.sdk" version="0.0.0.0" /> 
</dependentAssembly>
```

The file is in the project. Does anyone know how I can fix this, or at least troubleshoot it? There is no detail in the error message at all. I have also been told to use version="0.0.0.0".

Comment: Do you have the external DLL installed in GAC?

Comment: if your dependency can be obtained from NuGet, try to install it again, then go and see on the packages.config which is the version and then on your .config file, try to put the same version of the packages.config

Comment: Maybe the problem is not so obvious, hinges on "requires me to use manifest dependencies".  These manifest entries are only useful for unmanaged DLLs.  And sure, low odds that this file can be found in c:\windows\winsxs, only Microsoft ever uses it.  The .NET framework has its own equivalent, it is the GAC.  Most obvious way to get ahead is to *not* tinker with the manifest and see what goes wrong next.  And use a telephone to verify the stated requirement, it smells very fishy.

Comment: I think I can get down the road faster, if I solve the fact the dependent assembly.manifest isn't even being found - let alone the DLL's in them - Is there a solution to that?

Comment: @Zinov thank you but it's not available in NuGet.

Comment: @Kurubaran it is not in the GAC, says it must be used as a private assembly, manifest-based deployment.

Comment: @HansPassant I think you're on to the problem, but if I just drop it in as-is, it just says it can't find the file.

Comment: basically you need to match the versions, after you add your reference, please press F4 over the reference and check the version. Same advise I  gave you before. If you have it in the gac, then you should see how many version of the assembly are hosted in the GAC and choose the correct version. Normally they are on this location %windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly or use the gacutil.exe tool with -l parameter, it should give you the entire path gacutil –l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem went away, when under "Project Properties", "Security", I removed "Enable OneClick security Settings". With lack of detail on the error message, I can only guess that it has something to do with these vendor provided DLL's may not be signed. If anyone has any info, feel free to comment I'd appreciate it.

Thanks everyone!